# Kotlin convert FileTime to day, month, year

Tags: kotlin, filetime

**Problem:**

I have got a directory of files, which have a creation date.

What I am trying to reach is to get the value of the creation date day, month and year.

However, I am working with a FileTime.

I was expecting to be able to call a GetMonth method or such.

Unfortunately, this is not possible, does someone know a nice solution to get the day/month/year of a FileTime?

**What have I tried:**

- I have tried to convert this to the Date type. This is possible, but here are the day, month and year methods deprecated.
- I have tried to use to get the milliseconds of the FileTime, but this did not feel like a pretty solution.

**Final question:**
How do I get the day, month and year of a FileTime?

Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 5):

## `FileTime` ➙ `Instant` ➙ `ZonedDateTime`

I'm assuming that you're using Java 8 or later. You must convert the [`FileTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html) to an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). You can then apply a `ZoneId` to the `Instant` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object for the time zone you want the date in. The below code converts the `FileTime` to date in [India time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India).

```
val zonedTime = fileTime.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))
println(zonedTime.year)
println(zonedTime.monthValue)
println(zonedTime.dayOfMonth)
```